# Did I do something wrong while trying to recover files with foremost?

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery

When I run this command on foremost,

```
sudo foremost -i /dev/hda -o /recovery/foremost
```

I get,

```
Processing: stdin
```

Is this right or did I miss a step when I followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Foremost)?

Comment: Or I can't use foremost without a LiveCD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could add the option "-d" (which means "indirect block detection", that works fine with unix) and specify the kind of files you want to recover (like zip or jpg or ole).  The result:

```
sudo foremost -d -o /recovery/foremost -t jpg,ole,zip -i /dev/hda
```

Comment: That means that you can't recover the folders that the files where in?

Comment: Yes, the organization of the folders like we see is different from how they are write on disk.